# AS3/Flash: Flattening complex objects for transparency

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a complex movieclip object (an movieclip made up of other movieclips) that I want to fade in and out, but I don't want the objects that overlap to become visible during this fading process, I want to treat the whole thing like a bitmap for the duration of the fade. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the MovieClips inside your complex MovieClip to fade uniformly?

Answer (score 2):

Set blend mode to "Layer":

[image: blend-mode]

Layers with normal blend mode:

[image: normal blend mode]

Layers with layer blend mode:

[image: layer blend mode]

References:

- [Flash Professional / Applying blend modes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7d5ca.html)
- [ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html)